# Actionscript: Any solution to CameraRoll.addBitmapData's horrible quality?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, photo, camera-roll

I am adding some images to Android's system gallery with CameraRoll.addBitmapData. This all works just fine, however the quality of the added images is... how to put it... disastrous! Absolutely unusable. Considering the method doesn't accept any parameters, I am not quite sure what can be done about it. Is there any other way how to achieve this or this case is lost? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/abhisek-mishra/ScreenShot

Use the native extension above. If you need hel to use it, just ask for it. I´ll see what i can do for u if is the case.